# How to print the compiled instructions of V8 to Chromium console?

Tags: v8, chromium

I modified the V8 engine by add '--print-opt-code' to flag arrays, and now it can print the compiled code to console.Just like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1QV0.png)

And now I want to print these codes to Chomium console window, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV30z.jpg)

then what should I do?
Than you very much ~~

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, that's not supported. `--print-opt-code` always prints to stdout; there's no way to redirect its output to the DevTools console.

(Of course you could implement that, but I think it would be quite a bit of work.)